# Is it possible to initialize multiple lazy collections in parallel?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, jpa

I am maintaining existing code and I found the following code to initialize some lazy collections.

```
user.getListOne().size()
user.getListTwo().size()
user.getListThree().size()
```

It works well, but the problem it is sequential, and I think I can parallelize it.

I tried doing this creating my own threads, but I am receiving a warning, so I guess it is not possible doing this with my own threads:

> ERROR org.hibernate.AssertionFailure - HHH000099: an assertion failure
>   occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due
>   to unsafe use of the session)  org.hibernate.AssertionFailure:
>   possible non-threadsafe access to the session

Is there a way using JPA/Hibernate to initialize the collections in parallel?

Comment: Do you have any reason what so ever to perform this microoptimization?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes, this is used in the login, so I want to make it as fast as possible. The collections are user roles that can be fetched in parallel.

Comment: You are almost certainly pre-optimizing.  I would instead just eagerly fetch it for the login.  That will certainly be faster than later trying to parallelize the load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. The EntityManager is not thread safe, so it should not be accessed from multiple threads during your 'parallel' initialization, and the EM is the one that takes care of population those lists.

You can use query hints or entity graphs to forced eager loading of the collections during the object retrieval.

Comment: What about using multiple EntityManager objects, one for every thread?

Comment: Then, each of them will work with its own copy of the User object, and initlize only one of the collection, you will have 3 threads, and 3 different user objects. So it will not solve your problem.